# CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource deprecated. And looking for substitute

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, core-foundation

Along with a bunch of other things included in Apple's Load Preset Demo sample code, the call to CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource is now deprecated. But I can't find a substitute for it - neither an option-click nor a look at the reference tell me any more than that it is no longer the done thing.

```
CFDataRef propertyResourceData = 0;
Boolean status;
SInt32 errorCode = 0;
OSStatus result = noErr;

// Read from the URL and convert into a CFData chunk
status = CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource (
                                                   kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                   (__bridge CFURLRef) presetURL,
                                                   &propertyResourceData,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   &errorCode
                                                   );


NSAssert (status == YES && propertyResourceData != 0, @"Unable to create data and properties from a preset. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) errorCode, (const char *)&errorCode);

// Convert the data object into a property list
CFPropertyListRef presetPropertyList = 0;
CFPropertyListFormat dataFormat = 0;
CFErrorRef errorRef = 0;
presetPropertyList = CFPropertyListCreateWithData (
                                                   kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                   propertyResourceData,
                                                   kCFPropertyListImmutable,
                                                   &dataFormat,
                                                   &errorRef
                                                   );

// Set the class info property for the Sampler unit using the property list as the value.
if (presetPropertyList != 0) {

    result = AudioUnitSetProperty(
                                  self.samplerUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  0,
                                  &presetPropertyList,
                                  sizeof(CFPropertyListRef)
                                  );

    CFRelease(presetPropertyList);
}

if (errorRef) CFRelease(errorRef);
CFRelease (propertyResourceData);

return result;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For the properties:** `CFURLCopyResourcePropertiesForKeys` example property: `kCFURLFileSizeKey` and `kCFURLContentModificationDateKey`, or Foundation-style with `[NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:error:]`.

**For the data:** `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]`.

They're not documented as replacements, AFAIK. Most of these newer replacement APIs have been around for a few years now.

**Edit**

In this example you posted in the edit, the program makes no request for properties, so you just want the data at the URL `presetURL`.

You can achieve this by:

```
NSURL * presetURL = ...;
// do review these options for your needs. you can make great
// optimizations if you use memory mapping or avoid unnecessary caching.
const NSDataReadingOptions DataReadingOptions = 0;
NSError * outError = nil;
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:presetURL
                                      options:DataReadingOptions
                                        error:&outError];

const bool status = nil != data; // << your `status` variable

if (!status) {
 // oops - an error was encountered getting the data see `outError`
}
else {
 // use the data
}
```

Comment: I tried to convert the code in question (see edited post), but I'm on unfamiliar ground here, and I am not sure how to use dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error in place of code that returns a boolean.

Comment: I'm starting to get the picture, that helped a lot. So I'm guessing that CFPropertyListCreateWithData must now be replaced with something that uses the NSData object? At the moment the NSAssert is failing due to propertyResourceData still being 0.

Comment: @stugrimshaw `NSData` and `CFData` are the same type -- just different names for different languages. see: toll free bridging. this allows you to use NSData as CFData (or the other way around) using a simple typecast. that API was just the first that came to mind for accomplishing this task in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could remove even more code by using just the following:

```
OSStatus result = noErr;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:presetURL];
id propertyList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:NULL];

// Set the class info property for the Sampler unit using the property list as the value.
if (propertyList) {
    result = AudioUnitSetProperty(
                                  self.samplerUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  0,
                                  (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)propertyList,
                                  sizeof(CFPropertyListRef)
                                  );
}

return result;
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using this code https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2283/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011217-CH1-TNTAG2

```
- (OSStatus) loadSynthFromPresetURL: (NSURL *) presetURL {

OSStatus result = noErr;

AUSamplerInstrumentData auPreset = {0};

auPreset.fileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef) presetURL;
auPreset.instrumentType = kInstrumentType_AUPreset;

result = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.samplerUnit,
                              kAUSamplerProperty_LoadInstrument,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              0,
                              &auPreset,
                              sizeof(auPreset));

return result;
```