# PDFKit class calling deprecated method?

Tags: cocoa, pdf, osx-mavericks, deprecated

I initialized a PDFDocument from a URL, and got the following message:`<Error>: CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: failed with error code -15.`While I have yet to determine whether or not this "Error code 15" is my bad; I looked up `CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource`, and found it was deprecated in OS X 10.9. I'm a relatively new programmer, so I've steered pretty well clear of deprecated methods. Is it okay to use them? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes you should avoid deprecated methods, as they will not work. However, this thread should be able to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020074/cfurlcreatedataandpropertiesfromresource-deprecated-and-looking-for-substitute

Comment: Looks interesting, but is it even possible to change the methods an Apple-provided class calls?

Comment: Well if you subclass them, then yes, you implement them and you run your custom code below. However, I'm not sure how is this relevant as I didn't see any modifications in the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided for now to use a work around; calling the method `initWithData:` instead