# CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource replacement

Tags: macos, core-foundation

In OS X 10.9 CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource has been deprecated, does anybody knows if there is a core foundation replacement for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020074/cfurlcreatedataandpropertiesfromresource-deprecated-and-looking-for-substitute

Comment: That will work if i can use ObjC, but i have to use only the C API for this. I suppose i will just use fread to read the file and then copy then create a CDataRef object from the bytes.